# Why (1) is int and how it works

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 3.6, `x = (1)`and type of x is int, it's same as `x = 1`.
So what's the purpose of `()`? Why is it not a tuple?

Comment: Brackets can be used around any expressions, like `1 + (1 + 1)`. `1` itself is an expression, so brackets can be used around it.

Comment: `()` *is* a tuple, an empty one. Non-empty tuples require commas: `1,`.

Comment: Why is this question marked as a duplicate? I don't see any answers in attached question as author doesn't ask how to create a single item tuple, but rather what's the purpose of construction `(1)`, which only @Sweeper answered. @jonrsharpe @paul-rooney @bear-brown @bruno-desthuilliers

Comment: @deathangel908 there is no *"purpose of construction"*, `(1)` is `1`. The OP asked why it wasn't a tuple; if they still have questions they're welcome to edit to clarify. Note also you can only ping one user per comment.

Comment: `What defines a tuple is not the brackets, it's the commas` really good, my question may be not clear enough, but this is the answer I need, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences):

> A special problem is the construction of tuples containing 0 or 1
>   items: the syntax has some extra quirks to accommodate these. Empty
>   tuples are constructed by an empty pair of parentheses; **a tuple with
>   one item is constructed by following a value with a comma (it is not
>   sufficient to enclose a single value in parentheses)**.

What defines a tuple is not the brackets, it's the commas, so `(1, 2, 3)` is a tuple, but it's not because of the brackets, it's because of the commas which means just using `1, 2, 3` would work the same. A tuple with no elements is represented with empty brackets (e.g. `()`). A tuple with one element is represented with a value, followed by a comma (e.g. `1,`).

Comment: *"A tuple with one element always unpacks itself"* - no, without the comma it's *not a tuple to start with*. A one-tuple *doesn't* unpack itself, as your example `x = (1,)` shows; `x` is then a tuple, not the unpacked integer. Also the parentheses are optional there, `x = 1,` works too.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh man, you're right! I always though that the brackets define a tuple, it's commas that define a tuple, brackets are just so it'd be more easily distinguish. If it wasn't for your comment, I'd always thing that brackets define a tuple. I'll update my answer so it's correct. Thanks!

Comment: Really? It's in the docs *you quoted from*: *"A tuple consists of a number of values separated by commas... they may be input with or without surrounding parentheses"*. That's *why* 0- and 1-tuples are a *"special problem"*.

Comment: I knew what kinds of capabilities a tuple had from other sources and I don't think I've ever heard them specify commas being the crucial part, I never looked at the docs to see how tuples are formed as I though I knew that. I never thought about tuples like that. Now even generator generator comprehensions make sense, the brackets always confused me. I can't believe this went over my head! I guess I just have to look at the docs thoroughly next time I want to post an answer.